# Show that $(0, 1)$ fails Heine-Borel.

Tags: real-analysis

So I think I understand the Heine-Borel property, but I want to make sure I've wrapped my head around it. With the help of @C Squared I was able to come up with the following, but I want to make sure it's okay. Thanks!

Let $I_k = (\frac{1}{k}, 2)$. Observe that $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ covers $(0, 1)$. Let $x\in (0, 1)$. It follows by the achimedean principle that there exists some natural number $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k} < x$. We may now conclude,
\begin{equation*}
0 < \frac{1}{k} < x < 1 < 2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x \in (\frac{1}{k}, 2), k \in \mathbb{N}^+.
\end{equation*}
so,
\begin{equation*}
x\in\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{k}, 2).
\end{equation*}
therefore,
\begin{equation*}
(0, 1) \subset (1, 2) \cup (\frac{1}{2}, 2) \cup  (\frac{1}{3}, 2) \cup \dots = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k
\end{equation*}
Now, Heine-Borel insists that there exists a finite subcover for every cover of $(0, 1)$ that also covers $(0, 1)$. So to show that $(0,1)$ is not compact we must show that the finite subcovers of $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$ do not cover $(0,1)$.

Suppose a finite subcover ($\bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$) of $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$. Then we have,
\begin{equation*}
(0, 1) \not\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n (\frac{1}{k}, 2),
\end{equation*}
because $\frac{1}{n+1} \in (0, 1)$ but $\frac{1}{n+1} \not\in (1, 2) \cup \dots \cup (\frac{1}{n}, 2)$ (by the definition of this set).

There exists a finite subcover that does not cover $(0, 1)$, so the set fails Heine-Borel and is not compact.

Comment: Heine-Borel does not insist that a finite subcover for every cover of (0,1) also covers (0,1), because that is just the definition of compactness. Heine-Borel is a theorem that can be applied in the $\mathbb{R}^n$, which states that a set is compact iff it is bounded and closed. The set (0,1) is bounded, but obviously not closed, So by Heine-Borel it is not compact.

Comment: But using the fact that the set is not closed doesn't mention anything about open covers. I have to show that there exists an open cover of A such that all the finite subcovers fail to cover A.

Comment: But your wording is *weird*.  $(0,1)$ *doesn't* fail Heine-Borel.  ANd "Now, Heine-Borel insists that there exists a finite subcover for every cover of (0,1) that also covers (0,1)" is completely false.  In fact because $(0,1)$ is open Heine-Borel *actually* insists on the *exact* opposite that there must exist an open cover with *NO* finite cover.

Comment: @fleablood I think OP was reaching for contradiction, but the wording was clumsy or not precise

Comment: I'll try to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: The OP is confusing the Heine-Borel property with the definition of Compact.  They are not the same thing.  The Heine-Borel property means the H.B Theorem is true in the space that has the property.  $\mathbb R$ has the HB property.  $\mathbb Q$ does not. $(0,1)$ as a space *does*.  ANd the fact that $(0,1)$ as a set is both i) *not* compact and ii) not closed and bounded. Confirms it.  $(0,1)$ does *not* fail the HB property. It *satisfies* it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Heine-Borel theorem, you need only show that $(0,1)$ is not closed. Since $0,1$ are limit points of $(0,1)$, and $0,1\not\in[0,1]$, then $(0,1)$ is not closed, therefore it cannot be compact.

Alternatively, if you suppose that $(0,1)$ is compact, then consider the cover $$\mathcal{U}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k},2)$$ By assumption, $\mathcal{U}$ admits a finite sub-cover, $$\mathcal{U}'=\bigcup_{k=1}^n(\frac{1}{k},2)$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, notice that $(\frac{1}{n},2)=\mathcal{U}'$.

We claim that $(0,1)$ is not a subset of $(\frac{1}{n},2)$.

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $\frac{1}{n+1}\in (0,1)$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}\not\in(\frac{1}{n},2)$, then $(0,1)$ is not a subset of $(\frac{1}{n},2)$, so $\mathcal{U}'$ is not a cover of $(0,1)$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, then no finite sub-cover exists.

Because we have found a cover of $(0,1)$, namely $\mathcal{U}$, that does not admit a finite sub-cover, then $(0,1)$ cannot be compact.

Answer (score 0):

As a subset of $\mathbb R$, $(0,1)$ is not compact.  That is because $\mathbb R$ has the Heine-Borel property and $(0,1)$ is not closed and bounded.  And you successfully gave an example of an open cover with no finite subcover.

But that is *not* what the question is asking.  The question is asking to think of $(0,1)$ as a *space* in and of itself, does *not* have the Heine-Borel property (which means that in $(0,1)$ as a *space* that the Heine-Borel Theorem is *FALSE*).

And to do that we consider the the set $(\frac 0, \frac 12]$.  This set is *CLOSED* in $(0,1)$ because it contains all its limit points (note $0$ does not exist in $(0,1)$ so $0$ is *not* a limit point of $(\frac 0, \frac 12]$).  And the set is bounded.

But it is not compact. Let $I_n = (\frac 1{n+2}, 1 - \frac 1{n+2})$.  $\{I_n\}$ is an open cover of $(\frac 0, \frac 12]$.  (For any $x \in (0, \frac 12]$ there is a $k\ge 3$ so that $\frac 1k < x$ so $x \in I_{k-2}$).  But it has no finite subcover as for any finite $\{I_n\}$ there is a $m= \min n$ and so if $0< x < \frac 1{m+2}$ we have $x$ not being covered.

So $(0,1)$ doesn't have the Heine-Borel Property because in $(0,1)$ the Heine Borel theorem is FALSE.